# How to add google api to .net c#

Tags: c#, api, gdata

How can i add the google data API to the .net framework. I saw the gdata documentation but was of no help. Now I am confused whether should I use web reference?

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a reference to the GData DLL (`Google.GData.Client.dll`) to your project. In Visual Studio, this can be accomplished by: "Select your project" => "Add Reference" => "Browse DLL's".

A detailed explanation can be found [here](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/dotnet_client_lib.html).