# How to use Cricket API for building a C# application

Tags: c#, api

I am a beginner to C# programming. I understand the concepts of OOP as I know java. I have an assignment of building a desktop application that works similar to the CricBuzz website, i.e I am supposed to show live schedules and score of ongoing cricket matches.

I heard that there are APIs that do this for me. I found the API online but the issue is, I do not know how to implement or use APIs in my C# program. Please help me out here.

TIA. :)

Comment: So what you've tried so far?

Comment: In this similar fashion, here's an example: [How to add google api to .net c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397154/how-to-add-google-api-to-net-c-sharp)

Comment: I don't know what to do exactly! I need to start from scratch actually. Have been looking for some sort of tutorial to learn what is the process to implement APIs. Couldn't find any. I have a URL which I think i am supposed to use right?

The link that I got the API is from www.cricapi.com

I don't know what to do with it now
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entities generated with [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/).
Using `JavaScriptSerializer` to deserialize json and a simple sequential `WebClient` call to download the json. You could improve on the quality and organization of this, try async, Newtonsoft.Json for serialization, etc. This is just a quick and dirty approach out of the many out there.

```cs
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using JsSerializer = System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer;
    using System.Net;

    //
    // http://cricapi.com/api/cricket/
    //
    namespace CricApi.Cricket
    {
       public class Provider
        {
            public string url { get; set; }
            public string source { get; set; }
            public string pubDate { get; set; }
        }
        
        public class Datum
        {
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string unique_id { get; set; }
        }
        
        public class RootObject
        {
            public Provider provider { get; set; }
            public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
            public bool cache { get; set; }
        }
    }

    //
    //http://cricapi.com/api/cricketScore?unique_id=946981
    //http://cricapi.com/api/cricketScore?unique_id=946765
    //
    namespace CricApi.CricketScore
    {
      public class Provider
      {
        public string pubDate { get; set; }
        public string source { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
      }
    
      public class RootObject
      {
        public bool cache { get; set; }
        public string inningsRequirement { get; set; }
        public string team2 { get; set; }
        public string team1 { get; set; }
        public string score { get; set; }
        public Provider provider { get; set; }
      }
    }
    // 
    // how to use this
    //
    namespace CricApi
    {
      class Program
      {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
        
          WebClient client = new WebClient();
          
          // Download cricket info
          //  dynamic dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);
          string cricketJson = client.DownloadString("http://cricapi.com/api/cricket/");
          Cricket.RootObject cro = new JsSerializer().Deserialize<Cricket.RootObject>(cricketJson);
    
          // Download cricket score info
          foreach (var datum in cro.data)
          {
            string uri = "http://cricapi.com/api/cricketScore?unique_id=" + datum.unique_id;
            string cricketScoreJson = client.DownloadString(uri);
            CricketScore.RootObject csro = new JsSerializer().Deserialize<CricketScore.RootObject>(cricketScoreJson);
          }
    
        }
      }
    }
```